# Calculate the colwidth while namest and namend appearing in "entry" element

Tags: xslt-2.0, xquery-3.0

> I am trying to Calculated of sum tgroup/colspec/@colwidth when namest
> to nameend appearing in entry element.
>
> I run the below XSLT code but expected output is not coming, Please
> help me Thanks in advance!
>
> **Input XML:**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <table>
>     <tgroup cols="9">
>         <colspec colwidth="60*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="12*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="12*"/>
>         <colspec colwidth="1*"/>
>     </tgroup>
>         <thead>
>             <row>
>                 <entry colname="col1"> </entry>
>                 <entry colname="col2"/>
>                 <entry colname="col3" namest="col3" nameend="col8">
>                     <b>My content here</b>
>                 </entry>
>                 <entry colname="col9"/>
>             </row>
>     </thead>
> </table>
> ```
>
> **My XSLT Code**
>
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="table">
        <table width="90%">
            <xsl:if test="tgroup/thead">
                <thead>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tgroup/thead/row">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                                <xsl:variable name="entrycol" select="@colname"/>
                                <td>
                                    
                                    <xsl:if test="(@namest ne '') and (@nameend ne '')">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@nameend,'col')) - number(substring-after(@namest,'col')) + 1"/>  
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:if test="@colname = ancestor::tgroup/colspec/@colname">
                                            <xsl:variable name="kk1" select="format-number(sum(ancestor::tgroup/colspec/@colwidth/xs:decimal(translate(., '*', ''))), '#.##')"/>
                                            <xsl:text>width:</xsl:text>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(ancestor::tgroup/colspec[@colname = $entrycol][1]/number(translate(@colwidth, '*', ''))  div number($kk1) * 100,'#.##'), '%')"/>
                                            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:if test="tgroup/tbody">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </thead>
            </xsl:if>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> **Expected Output**
>
> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <table width="90%">
>         <thead>
>             <tr>
>                 <td style="width:60%;">
>                     <p> </p>
>                 </td>
>                 <td style="width:1%;">
>                     <p></p>
>                 </td>
>                 <td colspan="6" style="width:28%;">
>                     <p>
>                         <b>My content here</b>
>                         
>                     </p>
>                 </td>
>                 <td style="width:1%;">
>                     <p></p>
>                 </td>
>             </tr>
>         </thead>
>         <tbody>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>             <tr> </tr>
>         </tbody>
>     </table>
> ```

Comment: What is that table input format, any well known or well defined table format? What is the output format, HTML? Have you checked whether libraries exist to transform between the two formats?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen: Input table format is DITA xml and output format is HTML

Comment: Please help me on this issue

Comment: But DITA OT certainly contains all the code to transform DITA to HTML.

Comment: Check whether https://www.dita-ot.org/ doesn't do the job already.

Comment: Right now we are not using DITA-OT, just simply we are using our xslt code and transform the DITA to Html

Comment: And what prevents you from using the toolkit? After all it is a tailor made tool for the input format you have to create HTML as one of its output format. It doesn't seem to make sense to try to develop a complex transformation for a complex format in a StackOverflow post if a toolkit exists that was developed to do that job.

Comment: In DITA OT there is no logic for calculating the colwidth that's why I am asking here, Please give suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That format is not clear to me but perhaps

```
   <xsl:template match="entry[@namest]">
        <xsl:variable name="col-range" select="@namest/xs:integer(replace(., 'col', '')) to @nameend/xs:integer(replace(., 'col', ''))"/>
        <tr colspan="{$col-range[last()] - $col-range[1] + 1}" width="{sum(ancestor::tgroup/colspec[position() = $col-range]/@colwidth/xs:decimal(translate(., '*', '')))}%">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
```

helps.